# Why do these two ways of associating a GUI element with an Action differ in their results?

Tags: java, swing, action

I am currently studying [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) tutorial.

The tutorial describes two different ways of associating a text-editing command (an `Action` instance) with a GUI element.

---

**Option 1:**

Get an array containing all available Actions from a specific `JTextComponent` by invoking `component.getActions()`. After that, sort them by name into a HashMap, and code a method that takes a name and returns an Action from the HashMap.

Then associating a GUI element with an Action on a JTextComponent is done like in the following example:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
...
menu.add(getActionByName(DefaultEditorKit.cutAction));
```

**Option 2:**

Instantiate the Action directly, and then associate a GUI element with it. For example:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Style");

Action action = new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction();
action.putValue(Action.NAME, "Bold");
menu.add(action);
...
```

---

The tutorial states that the Action used in option 1 would be shared by all JTextComponents in the application, while the Action used in option 2 would be used only by a single JTextComponent.

However, I'm not sure how this can be. Nowhere in option 2 is the Action bound to a particular JTextComponent, while in option 1 the Actions are received from a particular JTextComponent.

**Please explain why these two techniques differ in the results they generate.**

*(The examples are taken from the tutorial).*

Answer (score 0):

In Option 1, the same instance of `Action` might be passed into multiple GUI elements.  In Option 2, you make separate `Action` instances for each GUI element.  The difference is that if you modify the single instance in Option 1, all the GUI elements using that action would be updated, while in Option 2 only one element would change.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A question regarding this: In option 1, `getAction()` is invoked on a *particular* `JTextComponent`. What is actually returned? Are the returned Action objects 'exclusive' to that particular `JTextComponent`, and possibly 'linked' to it somehow? Or is the returned array more of a 'list' of Actions to 'let us know' what actions this JTextComponent supports, rather than a list of objects exclusively 'owned' by it?

Comment: @Prog, why don't you test it yourself? Create a simple program with two text components. Get the Action from both components and then compare the references of each component to see if they are the same or different. Or you could always look at the source code to see what the `getAction()` method does.